# iPhone4 change IMEI?

Tags: ios4, iphone-4, imei

Can I change the IMEI of an iPhone4?

It is just a hypothetical question, I am preparing for a little presentation to show off how easy it is to "hide" yourselves from anyone unwanted (even the carrier) and how people use this to do not pay for their phones, and because of this, I want to show off how easily it can be changed.

I've tried Googling it, but only found links to older versions of a particular app what only supports iPhone 3G(S).

So, could anyone help me in this? An app name or link would be perfect (IDK if ZiPhone3 can do it), and please before starting a rage war, THIS IS FOR PRESENTATION USE ONLY! I will never change the IMEI of a phone permanently!

Comment: So wouldn't the fact that you've had to come here to ask this question after not being successful elsewhere lead you to the conclusion that it actually *isn't* as easy as you say it is to change the IMEI of an iPhone?

Comment: As an aside the IMEI is only used to identify the phone. The SIM Card itself stores a number which is used to identify the subscriber.

Comment: It's a fact I'm not a patient Googler, after a few (about 30-40) fake founds I quit, so did I now. I'm just asking because maybe SOMEONE knows the answer. I know about the IMSI, but my presentation is about how to hide an iPhone, not the SIM card. Let's assume the card was swapped, and this is how easily it can be stolen, or hidden, etc. For the 3GS, I found a solution (ZiPhone3) but I don't know if it's possible with the i4, and that's what I'm asking here.

Comment: I'm interested in this topic too. In this country (turkey) you have to register "your" phone if you have bought it in another country. This process takes about 1 week. I had my iphone swapped at the tech service, so i have to, you guessed it, re-register it, which means i have to wait 1 week for my phone to get registered, which it already was. Now i am looking for a way to change the imei to the old one in this looong week. So sad